# Selenium C# SendKeys NullreferenceException was unhandled by user code

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, specflow

I am having a problem with entering some text into a textfield using SendKeys.
I get the error:

```
NullreferenceException was unhandled by user code
An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in companyautomation.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

During debug I found the Input field is null.  I do not know why the element is null, the locator seems to have not worked.  It is a simple ID for the locator.
I have checked the CSS for the locator for inspect element and it is correct.

The line the error is, Username field element is null

```
UsernameField.SendKeys(Username);
```

My code snippet is:

```
public class LoginPage : BasePage
{

    public LoginPage(IWebDriver Browser) : base(Browser)
    {            
    }

    public void EnterUsername(string Username)
    {
        UsernameField.SendKeys(Username);
    }

    [FindsBy(How = How.CssSelector, Using = "#LoginUsername")]
    private IWebElement UsernameField { get; set; }        
}

public class BasePage : DriverClass
{        
    protected IWebDriver Driver { get; set; }

    public BasePage(IWebDriver driver)
    {
        Driver = driver;
        PageFactory.InitElements(Driver, this);
    }

    //** All Page Objects **//
    #region Page Objects

    private LoginPage LoginPage => new LoginPage(Driver);
    private Browsers Browser => new Browsers();

    #endregion    
} 

[Binding, Parallelizable]
[Scope(Tag = "Login")]
public class LoginSteps : BasePage
{
    public LoginSteps(IWebDriver driver) : base(driver)
    {
    }

    [Given(@"I login with (.*) with password (.*)")]
    public void GivenILoginWith_Valid_UserWithPassword(string Username, string Password)
    {
        LoginPage.EnterUsername(Username);
        LoginPage.EnterUserPassword(Password);            
    }
```

The HTML:

```html
<input value=""
       data-val="true"
       data-val-required="Please enter a valid username"
       id="LoginUsername"
       name="LoginUsername"
       ng-blur="vm.analytics.push({ 'category' : 'Login' , 'action' : 'Left Username field', 'label' : 'Language: en'})"
       ng-focus="vm.analytics.push({ 'category' : 'Login' , 'action' : 'Enter Username field', 'label' : 'Language: en'})"
       placeholder="Username"
       title="Username"
       type="text">
```

Comment: Where are you initializing the LoginPage property in LoginSteps? Are you sure it's the UsernameField that is null, not the LoginPage property in your step definition class?

Comment: LoginPage is instantiated in the BasePage class, LoginSteps inherits BasePage.  How do I  initializing the LoginPage property in LoginSteps if I have not done it correctly? Thanks.